# Is light always in this dual state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality

Is light always in this dual state or when it is acting as wave, there is no particle nature and vice versa?

Comment: There really is no distinction between particle nature and wave nature.   In fact, light is neither.  It's a different thing altogether that takes a fair amount of time to describe.  It's a bit unfortunate that the distinction is often made in introductory courses, but the foundation needed to understand the current accepted picture takes more time to develop than an introductory course has available.  There's historical "precedent", though, in the sense that the current picture was developed in the 1940's.  Prior to that, I assume (but not sure) that physicists accepted duality.

Comment: what is the good place to start to understand what exactly is light then.?some good book.? website etc.?

Comment: @garyp user31058 said something without notifying you.

Comment: @user31058 if you want to understand this on the deep fundamental level, you are probably aiming for QED (Quantum Electrodynamics). I would start by studying Special Relativity and Quantum Mechanics (there are tons of literature on these subjects, just grab the one you like best). Then generic features of Quantum Field Theory and eventually Quantum Electrodynamics. Try Peskin-Schreder textbook, it isn't perfect but it worked for me. Overall, this can take about 4-12 months, depending on your current knowledge and on how much time you are willing to spend on this weekly.

Comment: Thanks @Dale.   [This paper](http://www-3.unipv.it/fis/tamq/Anti-photon.pdf) details the history of "photon", and explains the concept.    There are many articles [here](http://gerdbreitenbach.de/gallery/photon_what_is_a.pdf) but I can't vouch for them.  There are many entries here at physics SE, but they are of variable quality.

Answer (score 0):

> Is light always in this dual state or when it is acting as wave, there is no particle nature and vice versa?

In studying physics and the definitions of the concepts used in developing the mathematical models describing the data, one has to be clear of the framework of the discussion.

There are the following frameworks with different mathematical modeling:

1) Classical:

1.a) Newtonian mechanics

1.b) Maxwell's electromagnetic theory

1.c)statistical mechanics (the Newtonian mechanics of many body kinematics)

1.d)thermodynamics ( which is emergent from statistical mechanics)

2)[Quantum mechanical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics)

2.a)What is called first quantization with the solutions of Th Schrodinger equatiion on potential problems

2.b) Quantum electrodynamics (electromagnetism at the quantized level)

2.c) Quantum field theory ( applied to elementary particles)

2.d)Quantum statistical mechanics ( the statistical mechanics modifiedbyquantum solutions)

There is also special relativity  and general relativity, which should be classified in both frames.

Confusions and paradoxes arise if one mixes two frameworks without a clarifying statement.

The terminology "light" belongs to 1.b. The particle nature of light belongs 
2.d . I.e light as a classical concept is completely described by the solutions of the [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) which define it as a wave with excellent predictive power. The wave nature appears in the intensity of the magnetic and electric fields that [describe light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Electromagneticwave3D.gif).

The terminology "particle" and "dual" belongs totally  to the quantum mechanical framework.

So in the classical framework light is always described as a wave.

The story changes if the quantum mechanical level is examined. There light is emergent from an enormous number of particles [called photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), which build up the classical electromagnetic wave, and this [can be shown mathematically.](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html) .

Photons as elementary particles have the dual quantum mechanical nature. When detected as individual photons they display particle properties, i.e. localization in (x,y,z,t). But the *probability density* for finding the photon about this point, i.e. if many photons are detected, has a wave property. This can be seen clearly in this [double slit experiment](http://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/):

[image: photdbl]

> the diffraction of individual photon from a double slit recorded by a single photon imaging camera (image intensifier + CCD camera). The single particle events pile up to yield the familiar smooth diffraction pattern of light waves as more and more frames are superposed (Recording by A. Weis, University of Fribourg).

The first frames, top left, show individual photon hits, which seem random, while the accumulation shows the probability density of finding a photon, it has a diffraction pattern characteristic of the light frequency these photons build up.

Physics is not a simple subject, the concepts build up and a lot of mathematical modeling is needed to organize the observations and be able to predict new results. But the logical structure above of the frameworks in which one should work should be kept clear.

Comment: Thanks so much  @anna v it helps. So is it fair to say then that when we talk of single particle's or single's photon's wave nature, that wave is mathematical abstract wave i.e probability distribution. and not like our classical wave.

Comment: yes. The fact that the frequency nu of the light wave appears  as the h*nu of the photon energy is due to the fact that the photons obey a quantized version of the same Maxwell's equations.

Comment: thanks so much @anna v ..it helping to clear the stuff a bit. so thx much :) So when we say particle has wave partcile duality, it is slighly misleading then right.? as wave here is not the classical wave. It is probablity distribution right.? but then this probablity distribution should have some link with the classical wave as when single photon is sent thorugh doube slit,  we see the interference pattern which is classical wave.? I am still confused with link between classical wave and this probablity distributivo. Any help would be greatly appreciated thx so much

Comment: The smooth transition between classical "light" and qm "photon"comes because both are described by Maxwell's equations, the same E and B fields differential equation  turned into an operator eqution of the PSI of quantum mechanics, so there is continuity in the emergent classical light from the innumerable photons. see http://cds.cern.ch/record/944002/files/0604169.pdf

Comment: Thanks so much @anna v I have read lot of your answers on this site and I must say you have given the clearest answers to lot of very confusing concepts. Thanks so much..It is very helpful to so many people ..huge respect ..I am trying to learn Quantum mechanics (as hobby). Can you please recommend some intermediate level books to grasp QM I have read lot of popular books on QM and I want to get into little more rigour. thx so much for your help :)

Comment: Have a look at this https://cds.cern.ch/record/1634843?ln=en . I have not read it but  I have great respect for the CERN  site that recomends it .

Comment: Thx so much @ann v i have ordered it ..One of the things that is causing confusion is relation between wavelength and momentum. I get de Broglie equation but intutively how are they related is not making sense. any pointers or tips would be greatly appreciated thx as always ..